# UnauthorizedAccessException occured when try to read an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, readfile

I'm getting above exception when trying to access an XML file
Here is the code

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"path");
```

Comment: It would appear you don't have access to that path.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have access to that path.

Comment: especially the "{whereever}\path." you are trying to load.

Comment: Thank you guys ..
found the fault
i didnt have access to that path
thanks guys
appriciate your help